# dynamically defining carouselview fails but there is no problem when it is defined in xml file

Tags: android

I can use a carouselview ([Link](https://github.com/sayyam/carouselview)) defined in a xml
But when I try to use a carouselview dynamically, I have the following error:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setAdapter(android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter)'
>   on a null object reference

The code is as following:

```
CarouselView carouselView111;
carouselView111 = new CarouselView(getApplicationContext());

final int[] sampleImages = {R.drawable.a1, R.drawable.koalasplash2,R.drawable.logo1,R.drawable.logo2};

mLayoutStruct_M4_Configurations_NewPage.getLayout_table_1_Row_3_Imageview1().addView(carouselView111);

carouselView111.setPageCount(sampleImages.length);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the carousel lib doc, but #addView(...) will start triggering the view displaying process.

When you add the view, the carousel should be ready to display, which does not seem to be true in your case. Maybe finish the initialisation of the carousel before adding it to your layout.